# Count Lines of Code in Xcode Targets

Tags: xcode, perl, scripting, xcode6, cloc

I thought this question would have been asked a million times, but to my surprise I found no answer. I have an Xcode project that has 3 targets. I use Perl's cloc to count the lines of code for the whole .xcodeproj. I want to count the lines in the individual targets instead. Where is the target location of a project in the Finder?

Comment: AFAIK all targets messed up in one project file, only schemes for them live in different files

Comment: @sage444 Interesting, thank you. If you want to add that as an answer I'll mark it correct.